# Using python to write hex to file

Tags: python, file, encoding, hex

I am trying to create a bunch of binary files that contain corresponding hex values

```
for i in range(2**8):
    file = open("test" + str(i) + ".bin", "wb")
    file.write(hex(i))
    file.close()
```

Unfortunately it appears that a text representation of my counter converted to hex is being written to the files instead of the actual hex values.  Can someone please correct this code?  I'm sure the problem is with `hex(i)`

Comment: Well, yes... `hex(x)` docs specifically say that it returns a string. http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex But hex is a representation: do you want to write the binary representation of that hex string? Or the binary representation of `i`?

Comment: I suppose you want to write the binary value of i instead of literal value of i to file?

Comment: You will want to use [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the value to be written in binary, use *chr()* to create the character from *i*:

```
for i in range(2**8):
    with open("test" + str(i) + ".bin", "wb") as f:
        f.write(chr(i))
```